# VisualGC Download for offline installation

Tags: java, download, jvisualvm

I need to install the visualGC plugin for jvisualvm on an **offline** machine.
So I have to download the *.nbm file first. The links on [this](http://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html) site are all down (http/404).

Where can I get this file?

Comment: Try this one https://java.net/downloads/visualvm/release136/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-visualgc_1.nbm.

Comment: The HTTP 404 issue has been fixed. The links on the [Plugins Center](http://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html) page are now working again.

Comment: @SubOptimal dead again.

Comment: @SubOptimal thanks ...

Answer (score 15):

As `java.net` has been closed the following should work for the future.

On http://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html it's stated that the new VisualVM homepage is https://visualvm.github.io.

On that page below the download button there is a link to the [plugins center](https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html).

[image]

On next page click the link below your VisualVM version (e.g. [1.3.6](https://visualvm.github.io/archive/uc/release136/updates.html)).

[image]

On the related updates page you find in section `Tools` the link to the [VisualGC plugin](https://visualvm.github.io/archive/downloads/release136/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-visualgc_1.nbm).

[image]

Comment: Thanks it really helped.